# Why symbols in assembly language are used before they are defined?

Tags: assembly

As part of our university project we have to write a mini-assembler. It's a two-pass assembler. I was wondering why it is allowed in assembly language to use symbols, in opcodes for example before they're actually declared (later in code)? I assume there must be a reason for this because in most of programming languages that I know first you declare a variable then you use it. Moreover if this were the case in assembly language, two-pass assemblers won't need to exist I guess.

Comment: Take a few minutes to look at some assembler code, e.g. the one generated with `gcc -O -fverbose-asm -S` as I suggested in my answer.

Comment: In most high-level languages you can `goto x` before having seen `x:`. This isn't unique to assemblers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You often jump to some forward location, or pass some constant (i.e. the named address of some literal string) defined forward to a assembler instruction. In both cases, a use before define is needed.

As an example, take some non trivial C code `foo.c`, and ask your [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler to emit the assembler code for it using `gcc -O -fverbose-asm -S foo.c` then look into the generated `foo.s`; and it would be better to do that on some existing C source file of several hundred lines at least (e.g. from some existing free software project).

BTW, it is mostly a matter of convention. One could imagine some assembler syntax requiring some `.FORWARD symb` directive to explicitly declare some `symb` to be used forward. But historically assembler programs where not written that way (and most assemblers don't even have any syntax to declare but not define a symbol). And requiring a `.FORWARD` directive for each use before define symbol is a burden: you'll need a lot of such directives in practice. So better avoid them.

Notice that some recent (and higher level) programming languages do not require to forward declare symbols, in particular the [Go language](https://golang.org) permits you to call a function by name without it having been forward-declared.

<sup>(there are also other reasons why an assembler is a two-pass thing : assemblers are producing [object files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_file) with [relocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relocation_(computing)) information)</sup>

BTW, every machine code program has some kind of loops, so the [control flow graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_flow_graph) is cyclic. If it wasn't, your program would exit very quickly (in a fraction of a second). Loops (or their equivalent, e.g. recursion) are fundamental to computers. Most conditionals (i.e. an `if` instruction in C) translate to *forward* conditional jumps in assembler. Read also about the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).

Notice that symbols (or labels, they are the same) are untyped in assembler code.

Comment: But all symbols have to be declared eventually. So if they have to be declared eventually why not just declare them on top and then write all the opcode code?

Comment: Assemblers don't *declare* symbols, just *define* them. It is a matter of convention.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. If it's just convention it seems like an  extremely strange convention to me as not only it's counter-intuitive but also adds so much work for programmer to do in order to support such convention.

Comment: No, it is not that much work. An assembler is really a simple (but tedious) program to code. Most of its complexity is related to the complexity of the underlying machine & instruction set. So that convention is very practical.

Comment: @Yos You're looking at it the wrong way. It's more intuitive and easier for the programmer using the assembler. How hard it's for the programmer writing the assembler is a secondary consideration.

Comment: If my assembler required me to forward declare every label when jumping forward... I would probably switch to a better assembler. Don't let precious customers flee away from your software! :-)

Comment: to be honest I didn't understand why when you jump forward it's easier to do this without forward-declaring a symbol. An example would be appreciated.

Comment: It is simply much shorter. If you have to `.FORWARD` every symbol which is jumped forward, your assembler code would have to be probably much bigger. As a practical example, take any realistic C code and compile it with `gcc -O  -S -fverbose`; I don't need to give one.

Comment: I did what you suggested and even after writing a loop in C, the assembly code didn't have any mentions of jump. What code should I write in order to observe this?

Comment: @MatteoItalia just to make sure we're on the same page: when I say declaring symbols first I mean variables not labels. Does the same still hold true with varuables?

Comment: Did you take some *realistic* code? For example, download the source code of `bash`, compile it, and look into the produced assembler. Perhaps a tiny C program of a few lines won't need forward jumps. But realistic programs do. At the assembler level, variables and labels are the same kind of symbol.

Comment: I'm mostly talking about labels placed inside code, but why are you making a distinction? To an assembler they are exactly the same thing. You call it variable, I call it label to a location that happens to contain garbage (or zeroes or whatever) instead of code.

Comment: @Yos in most of the assemblers there are no variables, what are talking about?

Comment: @Ped7g by variable I meant assigning an address to a data (integers/string).

Comment: @Yos not sure what assembler you have on mind, I can recall only MASM doing this. Everything else is just doing "labels" into memory, not connecting it to the way how the resulting bytes are defined (in NASM `varA db 'A'` is same as `varA:` \n `db 'A'`  or as `varA: inc ecx` ... all three of them produce in 32b mode the same machine code and symbol table contains the same "varA" label).

Answer (score 2):

Assemblers will add a symbol to their symbol table as soon as the symbol is encountered when it is either referenced or defined. During the first pass, the assembler makes assumptions about the symbol type (size, located in data or code section, ...), but doesn't need to know the actual address.

When the symbol is defined, then it's value is stored into the symbol table entry for use during the second pass.

There are multi-pass assemblers that reduce code size related to forward references that affect instruction size.

Comment: I think you're just describing how assemblers work. This is not my question though.

Comment: @Yos - The key point in my answer is that the assembler can make assumptions about a symbol. For example, if a symbol is the operand of a branch instruction, then the assembler can assume it's going to be a label somewhere in the code section (or else the assembler will indicate an error if the symbol ends up being defined outside of where branch instruction operands could be).

Comment: But how is that related to my question? I specifically asked what is the logic behind the fact that operations on symbols precede symbol declarations.

Comment: In most programming languages that support `goto`, which is the same as a branch in assembler, both `goto` and a branch can be forwards to a label that isn't defined yet. The main difference is that this same logic also applies to variables in assembler, for example the data section where variables are defined may occur after the code section in assembly.

Comment: "The main difference is that this same logic also applies to variables in assembler, for example the data section where variables are defined may occur after the code section in assembly."  - So do you know what is the logic behind that difference?

Comment: @Yos - It's probably a legacy issue. Consider the case where code and data are common to a single section in a program, such as a MSDOS  .COM program, or the code / data in a partition or boot sector on a PC. It's common for most or all of the data to follow the code. (In the case of a boot sector, the code starts with a branch that goes around a small text area, but most of the data follows the code).